Pytorch - Facing issue parallalising feature generation
We want to generate features from video files using pytorch parallel package, code is available at
https://github.com/sunilsarolkarcds/ISL-SignLanguage-Translation/blob/master/extract_features.py
But we are not able to process video files in parallel, the code gets stuck right after spawn call. Can someone help understanding what us going wrong

please trim your code down to a [mcve] that is enough to evidence the issue.

@GillesGouaillardet fixed the link,

what is your command line and what is the output until it hangs?

@GillesGouaillardet We have changed our code quite a lot after this, this is our latest code, when I tried this code from my windows laptop it starts the processes but the same code on collab just ends, without any trace , looks like none of the process starts
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e1CIo_GVqVy2XSdIBIW8DICMc-ACGOSB/view?usp=sharing

Command line for modified code is python extract_feature_mp.py
